# Erro ao incluir urls de um app no urls.py do projeto

Tags: django, django-2.0, django-rest-framework

Estou no começo de um projeto com Django 2.2.1, criando os primeiros apps e fazendo as ligações entre as páginas. 
No urls.py do projeto, incluindo as urls de accounts funcionou (com o `include(accounts.urls)`, porém ao tentar fazer o mesmo para o app expenses náo estou conseguindo.

Quando rodo o runserver, aparece o erro `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf 'projeto.urls' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.`

Já pesquisei e tentei várias coisas que encontrei, mas nada está funcionando. Se alguém puder ajudar agradeço.

**urls.py** do projeto

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('expenses/', include('expenses.urls')),  # expenses app urls
    path('accounts/', include('accounts.urls')), #sign up
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')), #login and logout
    path('', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='home.html'), name='home'), #homepage
]
```

Arquivos do app `expenses`:

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('create/', views.CreateExpenseView.as_view(template_name='create_expense.html'), name='create-expense'), #create new expense
]
```

**views.py**

```
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView  
from .forms import ExpenseForm

#view for create a new expense
class CreateExpenseView(CreateView):
    form_class = ExpenseForm
    template_name = 'templates/create_expense.html'
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class Expense(models.Model):
    TYPE = (
        ('Type1', 'Type1'),
        ('Type2', 'Type2'),
        ('Type3', 'Type3'),
        ('Outros', 'Outros') #abre um campo para digitar
    )

    type = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=TYPE, null=True, blank=True) 
    value = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    num_installments = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True) #parcelas
    day_installments = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True) #dia de pagamento de cada parcela
```

[image: estrutura do projeto]

Comment: `path('create/', views.CreateExpenseView.as_view(template_name='create_expense.html'), name='create-expense')`

`template_name = 'templates/create_expense.html'`
não seria melhor declarar o template só na url ou só na view?

Comment: tentei fazer isso mas não resolveu :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Há dois urlpatterns `accounts/`:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('expenses/', include('expenses.urls')),  # expenses app urls
    path('accounts/', include('accounts.urls')), #sign up
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')), #login and logout
    path('', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='home.html'), name='home'), #homepage
]
```

Traduzido da documentação: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/urls/

> Nomeando padrões de URL
>
> Para realizar a reversão de URL, você precisará usar padrões de URL nomeados, conforme feito nos exemplos acima. A string usada para o nome da URL pode conter todos os caracteres desejados. Você não está restrito a nomes válidos do Python.
>
> Ao nomear padrões de URL, escolha nomes que **provavelmente não colidirão** com a escolha de nomes de outros aplicativos. Se você chamar seu comentário de padrão de URL e outro aplicativo fizer a mesma coisa, o URL que encontra o reverse() dependerá do padrão que estiver por último na lista de padrões de url do seu projeto.
>
> Colocar um prefixo em seus nomes de URL, talvez derivado do nome do aplicativo (como myapp-comment em vez de comment), diminui a chance de colisão.
>
> Você pode escolher deliberadamente o mesmo nome de URL que outro aplicativo, se desejar substituir uma exibição. Por exemplo, um caso de uso comum é substituir o LoginView. Partes do Django e a maioria dos aplicativos de terceiros assumem que essa visualização possui um padrão de URL com o nome de login. Se você tiver uma visualização de login personalizada e fornecer ao seu URL o nome de login, reverse() encontrará sua visualização personalizada contanto que esteja em urlpatterns depois que o django.contrib.auth.urls for incluído (se estiver incluído).
>
> Você também pode usar o mesmo nome para vários padrões de URL **se eles diferirem em seus argumentos**. Além do nome da URL, reverse() corresponde ao número de argumentos e aos nomes dos argumentos da palavra-chave.

Portanto, como seus padrões são **exatamente** iguais, sem parâmetros, pode ser a causa do problema.

Comment: acredito que isso não seja problema, fiz isso seguindo um tutorial e estava funcionando normalmente, o problema é quando adiciona o expenses mesmo

Comment: Melhorei a resposta com uma citação da documentação.

Comment: eu tirei um dos accounts/ e continua dando o erro, pelo que entendi da citação, nesse caso não tem problema porque eles se referem a apps diferentes

Comment: Vamos analisar melhor a mensagem de erro: 

1. The included URLconf 'cedimfinanceiro.urls' does not appear to have any patterns in it. ** O nome do seu projeto é cedimfinanceiro? Então esse arquivo de que ele reclama é o urls.py do projeto? Poderia incluir a estrutura do seu projeto na postagem?

2. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import. ** Se o arquivo citado tem padrões de url válidos, o problema pode ser de circular import. A estrutura do projeto pode ajudar a esclarecer se há essa possibilidade.

Comment: editei e adicionei a estrutura do projeto

Comment: Todos os seus __init__.py estão vazios? Só pra retirar uma suspeita, poderia fazer o seguinte teste? No urls.py de expenses, mude `from . import views` para `from .views import createExpenseView`, mudando a chamada logo abaixo (retirando views.)